# Convert a string to two doubles

Tags: php

If I have a string like this: '(1.23123, 4.123123)'

How would I convert it to two doubles?

```
$items = explode(',', $string);

$n1 = $items[0] // (1.23123
```

My attempts:

```
floatval($n1) // 0
(double) $n1 // 0
```

How can I convert?

Comment: You need to remove the parentheses and whitespace before converting the values to numbers.

Comment: <?php
$string     =   '(1.23123,4.123123)';
$items = explode(',', trim($string,')('));
$aa = array_map('floatval', $items);
var_dump($aa);
echo '<pre>';print_r($aa );echo '</pre>';
?>

Comment: @Zeeshan, The [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22682230/1003917) was already been put up before you wrote the above comment. Also, if you want to answer please do it below and not on the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `trim` those parenthesis around your string . Use `trim` inside your `explode` by passing the parentheses as the charlist.

```
$items = explode(',', trim($str,')('));
```

#### The code

```
<?php
$str='(1.23123, 4.123123)';
$items = explode(',', trim($str,')('));
$items=array_map('floatval',$items);
echo $n1 = $items[0]; // "prints" 1.23123
echo $n2 = $items[1]; // "prints" 4.123123
```

Comment: what about the space ` ` in the second part of the string?

Comment: oh, I see. I thought `trim` will remove only what in second parameter. Thanks

Comment: @SaifHamed, You can pass whole charlist what is needed to be trimmed :)

Comment: Just to be clear, trim will **not** trim the inside-whitespace. First because it's not in the list of *to-trim-characters* (`')('`), and second because trim will only work on the boundaries of the given string. So no, trim will not take care of that too. It's `floatval` that's silently ignoring the whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. @SaifHamed, Please check Yoshi's comment for your question.

Answer (score 1):

`array_map('floatval', $array)` for your array

Comment: Nope , it will still fail as there are parenthesis around.

Comment: Wait, what? Answers shouldn't depend on other answers, at least not implicitly. If you want to say "xxx's answer, plus yyy", you need to say that. But, what happens if xxx's answer disappears?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
   $string = "(1.23123, 4.123123)";
   preg_match_all("/[\d\.]+/", $string, $matches);
   print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: did you mean `preg_match`? I've never heard of `prag_match`.